# Ext.Button 'overCls' not working in IE

Tags: button, extjs, extjs4

ExtJS4:

I want my Ext.Button to have my color when I mouse-over it. I wrote the following for this:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        text: "Submit",
        overCls: 'x-button-pressed'
    });
});
```

where 'x-button-pressed' is defined as:

```
.x-button-pressed{
    background: red;
}
```

This works fine in Mozilla 10 but IE 7. Please help.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but it should be background-color not background as you've only specified one property.

Comment: I tried background-color too. Its not working even in Mozilla. At least background is working in Mozilla. Do you have any other option to try in IE7?

Answer (score 0):

In EXT-all.css style for IE is written you can hide them.
Please check with below lines

```
/*
.x-nlg .x-btn-default-small-mc {
    background-image:none;
    background-color:transparent
}

.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small {
    padding:0!important;
    border-width:0!important;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0;
    -ms-border-radius:0;
    -o-border-radius:0;
    border-radius:0;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-position:1100303px 1000303px
}

.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-tl,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-bl,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-tr,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-br,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-tc,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-bc,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-ml,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-mr {
    zoom:1;
    background-image:url('../../resources/themes/images/eg_theme/btn/btn-default-small-corners.gif')
}

.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-ml,.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-mr {
    zoom:1;
    background-image:url('../../resources/themes/images/eg_theme/btn/btn-default-small-sides.gif');
    background-position:0 0
}

.x-nbr .x-btn-default-small-mc {
    padding:0
}
*/
```

if you are using ext js 4.1.1 v